# Data shown in admin panel not correct in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    #others
```

The food model is this:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="res")
    #others
```

And this is the review model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rest')
    food       = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
    #others
```

The problem I am having is: 
When I try to add a review model through the admin panel onto restaurant1, I don't get the food from restaurant1, but from all restaurants.

[image: Admin panel]

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior. You're just not using the right approach. What you'll want to use, are call [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines). This will allow you to have other forms in the parent form of a review.